# Java lambda show in textbox

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, textbox, java-stream

I have a problem to show a list in a textbox. I get an error and i don't know how to fix this.

I have a list of attenuators, this list I want to order by a "basic" quicksort-function.

```
public static <T> List<T> Quicksort(List<T> v, BiFunction<T, T, Integer> comparer)
{
    if (v.size() < 2)
        return v;

    T pivot = v.get(v.size() / 2);

    List<T> l = new LinkedList<T>(Quicksort(v.stream().filter(x -> comparer.apply(x, pivot) < 0).collect(Collectors.toList()), comparer));
    l.addAll( v.stream().filter(x -> comparer.apply(x, pivot) == 0).collect(Collectors.toList()) );
    l.addAll( Quicksort(v.stream().filter(x -> comparer.apply(x, pivot) > 0).collect(Collectors.toList()), comparer) );

    return l;
}
```

To use this function, I use a .map()- function on my list. So it needs only to order the double values and return them.

```
List <Double> orderdList = Quicksort(nodigeAttenuators.stream().map(Attenuator::getVerzwakking).collect(Collectors.toList()), null);

txtAttenuatorsFull.setText(orderdList.stream().map(Double::toString).reduce((acc, item) -> acc + " \n" + item).get());
```

I want to show this list of Doubles in an textbox and that where it goes wrong. I get this weird error.

```
txtAttenuatorsFull.setText(orderdList.stream().map(Double::toString).reduce((acc, item) -> acc + " \n" + item).get());
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      reference to toString is ambiguous
        both method toString(double) in Double and method toString() in Double match)
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says: there are two methods in Double that have a compatible signature and the compiler doesn't know which to choose. Since they are strictly equivalent, you can choose either.

For example, you can replace `map(Double::toString)` with:

```
.map(Object::toString)
```

to force the compiler to use the "standard", no-arg, `toString` method.

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution!

I have a problem with my sorting function (i see now). I get a "nullpointerexeption" at this line:




 List<T> l = new LinkedList<T>(Quicksort(v.stream().filter(x -> comparer.apply(x, pivot) < 0).collect(Collectors.toList()), comparer));

Comment: If `Object::toString` works, why doesn't `Double::toString`?

Comment: @markspace There is only one `toString` method in `Object` so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I changed it to `.map( d -> d.toString() )`, and now the `reduce` step returns an Optional and I have to call get(), it won't let me assign directly to a String.  Weird.

Comment: @markspace for reduce to return a String you would need to use the other reduce method that takes a value for "identity". Something like: `reduce("", (acc, item) -> acc + " \n" + item)` for example.

Comment: @assylias That produces a blank line at the very start of the string.  It "works" but is not ideal.  I found `.collect( Collectors.joining("\n") )` instead of `reduce` does what the OP wants without the questionable call to `get()`.